# How to generate a Roslyn TypeExpression for a type that has not yet been generated?

Tags: code-generation, roslyn

I have a chicken/egg problem here. I am using SyntaxGenerator to generate some classes. Some of these classes will have fields and properties whose types are types generated in other classes. So my question is how can you declare a field in a class that has a type defined in another generated class that has not yet been generated? Do I have to generate and compile all classes that the currently generated class depends on first?

```
    foreach (var attribute in datatype.Attributes)
    {
        var fieldName = $"_{MessageNode.FormatResourceName(attribute.Name)}";
        var fieldNode = Generator.FieldDeclaration(fieldName, Generator.TypeExpression(**???**), Accessibility.Private);
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can generate any type name you like, whether the type exists or not, using the `SyntaxFactory`.

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Simplification;

var name = SyntaxFactory
    .ParseTypeName("My.Generated.Type")
    .WithAdditionalAnnotations(Simplifier.Annotation);
```

Alternatively, for a simple name, you can use `SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName`, for a generic name you can use `SyntaxFactory.GenericName`. Equivalent API's exist to generate Visual Basic as well.